# Is there any way to find whether "#" key is pressed in OnKeyDown event of TextBox?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone

I am developing the application in the Windows Phone. I need the requirement in the KeyDown event of TextBox to be , I need to know when the "#" or "." keys are pressed in the TextBox. Can anyone help me to come out from this problem ?

Comment: I tried UnKnown key and PlateformKey code...

Comment: While debugging press '#' or'.' and check its KeyCode in KeyDown event. When you'll know keycodes you can use to detect when they are pressed.

Answer (score 6):

```
    private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.xxxx || e.PlatformKeyCode == xxxx) //xxxx is the keycode for your desired keys
        {
           //do work here
        }
    }
```

I think it should work

Comment: any application working on windows phone 7 will work on windows phone 8

Comment: But i get the same Plateform code for all the unknown keys in the Windows Phone 8. I am not able to differentiate using the PlateformkeyCode..

Comment: Are you making it specifically for windows phone 8? If yes then dont know about it since I dnt have the SDK to test it. It works on windows phone 7 hence should work on windows phone 8 according to what experts have said.

Comment: This part of the SDK is identical on WP7 and WP8.